# Use fingerprint auth as KeyGuard unlock instead of a pattern

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint

i want to allow user to use Finger Print as login option.
What i found for now is that we can use fingerprint as authenticate but the problem is it not related to password that my app using, and in my app i need to allow multi user login.
What i thought to do is use Android Key Store to generate SecretKey and require fingerprint to use it `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` and then encrypt in first time the password and store in Share Preferences later fetch it and fetch the SecretKey from Android Key Store and decrypt the problem is that KeyGuardManager by default allow only Pattern unlock and i can't find how to use Finger Print instead to fetch the SecretKey from Android Key Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback` to make sure that the fingerprint is correct and only after that user the Key from `KeyStore`.
When creating key in key store you can set timeout for its validity after last fingerprint auth.

Answer (score 0):

I used this lib to achieve that:
https://github.com/JesusM/FingerprintManager

What I do is after first successful login i show the user a dialog asking him to save his finger print, then I encrypt his password and store it in the shared preferences (with salt). Next time I decrypt it using finger print and sign in.